# Android studio - start QR code scanner from fragment

Tags: android, qr-code

I have been looking for an answer all over the internet.

The thing is, i found many ways to implement a QR code scanner in my app, in an activity.

This is one of the ways:

```
        scan_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan!!");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
```

Now i want to get it to work in a Fragment.
The problem is, it starts a new activity (the QR code reader)
Scans the QR code
But i dont get a response in my onActivityResult:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            System.out.println("Cancelled");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You cancelled the scanning!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Worked: " + result.getContents());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

But what is going wrong?

I guess it has to do with this part:

```
  IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
```

It gets the activity, but it is a fragment, instead of an activity.
How can i solve this problem?

Communicating first to my Activity which holds the fragment and then get the result ?
Please help, Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you will find the answer in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment Otherwise you have to share a bit more information about your code. Is the button ant the attached to the fragment or the activity itself? Is the shown onActivityResult method implemented in your fragment class?

Comment: Just pass fragment instead of getActivity in constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will presume that the implementation of the `onActivityResult` is on your `Fragment`, right?

The `IntentIntegrator` implementation on your `Fragment` is right. So, just remove your `onActivityResult` code from the Fragment and put it on the Activity.

I had a similar problem and this was my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator=
IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(FragmentNme.this);
```

It worked for me to solve my problem...rest all code is same.